# Laravel PWA Service Worker adding problem

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on laravel progressive web application . I initiate the service worker in `app.js` . My service worker file is in `./public` directoy . its name is `service-worker.js`.

but the problem is when i run the app in localhost its showing the folling error in console.

> **"uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type
>   ('text/plain').**"

So how can i solve this please tell me.
in app.js i included below code:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
{
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using nginx to serve your project then add this to server block this may solve the issue :

```
location ~ \.js {
     add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

Else if you are using apache then put this in httpd.conf (also ensure you have [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)) :

```
AddType text/javascript .js
```

This may solve your issue, generally if you don't include mime setups in your server setup you may face these issues. i suggest check your server setup first.

Comment: Actually the problem was from php artisan swoole:http server . works fine in artisan server or web server

Comment: try using homestead box you will get nice environment you can read more about the same at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead

Answer (score 0):

Check your netwrok requests, this error shows up when you are not loading the service-worker.js file correctly.

Make sure that you can really reach the service-worker.js file by the URL you are requesting

Comment: yes i can see them also. Its registered and i can see it from application/service-worker . And by clicking it i also can see its code also. But the problem is showing on console . And one more thing code that are inside the service worker is also not running